# crop image borders in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, plugins, crop

I have a lot of  images in many wordpress posts that have borders, 10px on each side.
How can I crop them away ?

I searched for plugins but couldn't find one that does the job

any help is appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin, or a way to create a plugin to achieve said functionality?

Comment: functionality if possible. thanks